# How can I install XML::DOM into my perl built from source?

Tags: perl

I downloaded the source to Perl and compiled/installed into a shared directory for my team. By default, Perl doesn't include XML::DOM and I need to add it to the installation. How do I do this?

I tried cpan and it installs to ~/perl5 by default. I tried cpanm next (cpanm -l $install_path XML::DOM) but perl still can't find it in @INC. I'm using perl 5.32.0.

Comment: Use `perlbrew` to manage the perl installation? It adjusts paths etc. so that modules are installed in the right place for the currently selected version.

Comment: Can you show your environment? Anything with `PERL` in it? Also, can you show me your cpan config (`cpan -J`). Also, showing the actual commands you ran would be very helpful.

Comment: I would really recommend using XML::LibXML instead of XML::DOM. It's substantially the same API, supports XPath, is significantly faster, and is actively maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call any cpan or cpanm, call cpan with your perl or inspect which perl is called with your tool by looking at the header.

`/path/to/my/perl -S cpan XML::DOM`

Comment: No luck - it's still install to ~/perl5. What's strange is the redhat6 and redhat8 versions of Perl seem to have XML::DOM, despite being built the same way. Only redhat7 is missing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have env var telling the module's installer to install it in an undesired place.

Unset the following env vars:

- `PERL_MM_OPT`
- `PERL_MB_OPT`